# Initial survey won't trigger a series of automated surveys. Can someone advice?

Tags: redcap

I have a survey called 'Set up and kill switch' (image 1) that will trigger a series of weekly surveys to be sent out, but it's not working. I'm not sure if I didn't set it up correctly or if the logic is not right. I attempted to set it up as sending surveys out via email. In step 3 (refer to image 2), I also specified the conditions: when the set up and kill switch survey has been completed and if the predetermined date in the survey matches the date 'today', the system should activate automated surveys for the next 8 weeks so participants should be receiving them on a weekly basis. However, when I tested this out, I did not receive a survey after completing the kill switch survey. Does anyone have experience in making something like this on redcap? I suspect that the logic is fine, but it could be an issue between linking participant IDs so they aren't receiving anything?

Logic code:

```
datediff([weekly_questionnai_arm_3i][weekly_date],"today","d","mdy",true)>=0 and ([weekly_questionnai_arm_3i][weekly_killswitch(0)])<>"1"
```

[Kill switch screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my5sk.jpg)
[Automated survey logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnbgH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the box next to 'Ensure logic is still true before sending invitation?'.

As soon the send logic is true the automated emails will be queued/scheduled for sending - changing the form fields so that the send logic is no longer true will *not* stop the scheduled emails from being sent unless the 'Ensure logic is still true ...' box is checked.

I also recommend clicking and reading the link underneath "How to use 'stop logic' to disable an automated invite".